# Rebasing with VSCode as git default editor in a "Remote SSH" connection

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote-ssh

There are many questions throughout SO about using VSCode as git's default editor.

The answer to all of them is to set

```bash
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

(or `"code -w"`)

However, this isn't behaving properly for me. I don't know if it's related, but I'm doing this via Remote SSH. And indeed, setting `"code --wait"` and then trying an interactive rebase gives me:

```bash
$ git rebase -i --root
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
```

So the `--wait` flag is clearly doing what it's meant to do. Likewise, a new tab is opened titled "git-rebase-todo"! However, the tab is empty except for an error: "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found."

[image]

If I try to open the file in a second tab, it also shows the same error. If I close the file, the rebase proceeds normally (as if I'd accepted the default "pick-all" setting).

I've also seen some references to using `"code -n --wait"`, and this does actually work!... sort of. It gets the job done, but since `-n` creates a new window, this actually generates a new SSH connection for each step (if I mark 10 commits as "edit", then it will open each commit in a new window, each of which takes a few seconds to complete the SSH connection).

Is there a way for this to "just work"? A setting that works across a "Remote SSH" connection that simply opens a new tab with the git-rebase-todo file that I can modify as needed and then all changes happen on the one window I'm using?

---

For the record, using `nano` or some other terminal-based editor works as intended: I make the changes there, and then the entire rebase happens one commit at a time on the currently open window/connection. I just want this same behavior without having to use a terminal-based editor.

Also, other operations (i.e. writing commit messages) work as expected with VSCode. The issue seems to only be when rebasing.

Comment: Did you ever find a work around? I've hit the same issue.

Comment: It just... started working. No idea what happened, sorry.

Comment: Hitting the same thing. I get:
Error: connect ENOENT /run/user/1002/vscode-ipc-b2d6f9ce-291a-49e1-9391-4a02037a5084.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/1002/vscode-ipc-b2d6f9ce-291a-49e1-9391-4a02037a5084.sock'
}
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.